# django modelform clean

Tags: django, django-forms

I've found a few posts that are similar in nature to this but they haven't been 100% clear so here goes:

In my views I have an `add_album` view that allows a user to upload an album. What I'd like to do is clean the form (`AlbumForm`) to check if this album is unique for an artist.

My `AlbumForm` looks like this:

```
class AlbumForm(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Album
    exclude = ('slug','artist','created','is_valid', 'url', 'user', 'reported')

  def clean_name(self):
    super(AlbumForm, self).clean()
    cd = self.cleaned_data
    try:
      Album.objects.get(slug=slugify(cd['name']), artist=artist)
      raise forms.ValidationError("Looks like an album by that name already exists for this artist.")
    except Album.DoesNotExist:
      pass

    return cd
```

So that's something along the lines of what I'd like to do.

My questions is: is there a way to pass the `artist` object from my view to the form so I can use that `artist` instance in the `clean` method?

I think I am looking at overriding the `__init__` method of the `ModelForm`, but I am unsure how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A better way to do this is at the model level, with the built-in Meta option, [`unique_together`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together).

If you've got a model `Album`, then you can probably do something like this:

```
def Album(models.Model):
   ...

   class Meta:
     unique_together = ("artist_id", "title")
```

Comment: I'm trying this but it doesn't seem to work. My "artist" field is a ForeignKey to an Artist model. So I do: unique_together = ('artist', 'slug') -- not 100% on how this is supposed to work.

Comment: Try `unique_together = ("artist_id", "slug")`. Not completely sure whether `unique_together` works with ForeignKeys.

Comment: Oh hey silly me, I forgot this was a database level change (didn't run migrations). It's working, thanks, this is a lot better.